# Required color-theme file missing in Emacs 26

Tags: themes, colors

After upgrading my OS (Ubuntu, from 18.04 to 19.04), my favorite text editor was automatically upgraded from Emacs 25 to Emacs 26. I then encountered a familiar error message at start-up:

```lisp
File is missing: Cannot open load file, No such file or directory, color-theme
```

The relevant portion of my configuration file, `.emacs`, is the
following:

```lisp
(add-to-list 'custom-theme-load-path "~/.emacs.d/themes/")
(add-to-list 'load-path "/path/to/color-theme.el/file")
(require 'color-theme)
(eval-after-load "color-theme"
    '(progn
     (color-theme-initialize)
     (color-theme-subtle-hacker)))
```

This works fine with emacs 25 or earlier versions, under Ubuntu
18.04. Naturally, the relevant file, `color-theme-subtle-hacker.el` is
located in `~/.emacs.d/themes/`.

I imagine that there are at least **two possible solutions** to this problem:

(i) There is a way to "tell" Emacs 26 where is the relevant
color-theme package. The problem could, in fact, be due to the
OS upgrade.

(ii) I could also force Ubuntu 19.04 to use Emacs 25. However, I would have
to install it manually, since every attempt at installing Emacs
currently leads to version 26.

Comment: The error message says that Emacs can't find the `color-theme` "package", not that the color theme package can't find the theme you chose.  I.e. it probably errors at `(require 'color-theme)`.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, this was indeed what I had understood. The problem is to do with finding the package, 'color-theme'.

Comment: Put `color-theme.el` in your `load-path`, in your init file, before trying to `require` it. (If you haven't downloaded `color-theme.el` then that's of course the first step.)

Comment: The `load-path` is a list of directories, *not* absolute path(s) to file(s).  The question states that the O.P. is adding an absolute file path of the color-theme file to the `load-path`, instead of merely ensuring that the directory containing the file is added to the `load-path`.

Comment: In addition, custom-theme-load-path is not used for the color-theme package.

Comment: I have done two things: (1) Putting `color-theme.el` in `.emacs.d`, but this hasn't solved the issue; and (2) I have tried to identify my `load-path` doing ‘C-h v load-path RET’, but this returns that `v is undefined`. Is there a way to identify my load-path, without a keyboard shorcut? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I report my solution, as I found the other answer quite misleading: since version 22.1 Emacs has built-in support for themes, and `color-theme` is obsolete, see the [package page](https://melpa.org/#/color-theme) on MELPA.

One can install and use `color-theme-modern` instead (on [MELPA](https://melpa.org/#/color-theme-modern)) or if you have Emacs 24 or above, just download the theme file and load it directly, as shown [here](https://github.com/juba/color-theme-tangotango#manual-emacs-24).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. I have found one solution to this problem. It was sufficient to download the `color-theme.el` and the `color-theme-library.el` and to copy them in  `~/.emacs.d/themes/`. Together with the simplified code in one's `.emacs` file eliminate all errors at start-up.

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/themes/")
(require 'color-theme)
(eval-after-load "color-theme"
    '(progn
     (color-theme-initialize)
     (color-theme-subtle-hacker)))
```

Thanks to @Drew, @lawlist, @InHarmsWay and @Stefan for your help. It seems that the files from the `emacs-goodies` package weren't accessible by my `.emacs` file, after upgrading to the latest Ubuntu distribution.